# error downloading packages with yum : permission denied

Tags: centos7, yum

i want to install simple screen recorder on my centos 7 , but when i hit command

```
yum install simplescreenrecorder
```

Output was this:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.praction.in
 * epel: sg.fedora.ipserverone.com
 * extras: mirrors.praction.in
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: mirror.vutbr.cz
 * updates: mirrors.praction.in
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package simplescreenrecorder.x86_64 0:0.3.11-6.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libQtGui.so.4()(64bit) for package: simplescreenrecorder-0.3.11-6.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libQtCore.so.4()(64bit) for package: simplescreenrecorder-0.3.11-6.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package qt.x86_64 1:4.8.7-3.el7_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: qt-settings for package: 1:qt-4.8.7-3.el7_6.x86_64
---> Package qt-x11.x86_64 1:4.8.7-3.el7_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmng.so.1()(64bit) for package: 1:qt-x11-4.8.7-3.el7_6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libmng.x86_64 0:1.0.10-14.el7 will be installed
---> Package qt-settings.noarch 0:19-23.10.el7.centos will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

==================================================================================
 Package               Arch    Version              Repository               Size
==================================================================================
Installing:
 simplescreenrecorder  x86_64  0.3.11-6.el7         rpmfusion-free-updates  1.3 M
Installing for dependencies:
 libmng                x86_64  1.0.10-14.el7        base                    171 k
 qt                    x86_64  1:4.8.7-3.el7_6      base                    4.6 M
 qt-settings           noarch  19-23.10.el7.centos  updates                  18 k
 qt-x11                x86_64  1:4.8.7-3.el7_6      base                     13 M

Transaction Summary
==================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+4 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 19 M
Installed size: 55 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:


Error downloading packages:
  1:qt-4.8.7-3.el7_6.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 13] Permission denied
  simplescreenrecorder-0.3.11-6.el7.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 13] Permission denied
  qt-settings-19-23.10.el7.centos.noarch: [Errno 5] [Errno 13] Permission denied
  1:qt-x11-4.8.7-3.el7_6.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 13] Permission denied
  libmng-1.0.10-14.el7.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

what is the cause of this and what could be the remedy ?

Comment: Either you forgot to run the command as root (sudo) or the permissions are screwed up on your filesystem.

Comment: I think permissions are messed up , because i am root already! So how to reset permissions?

Answer (score -3):

In the beginning of the following two directories, the python instead python2

```
sudo vi /usr/bin/yum
sudo vi /usr/libexec/urlgrabber-ext-down
sudo vi yum 
sudo vi yum-config-manager
sudo vi yum-debug-restore
sudo vi yum-groups-manager  
sudo vi yum-builddep
sudo vi yum-debug-dump 
sudo vi yumdownloader
```